# Solidworks API AddMenuItem

Tags: c#, solidworks

I'm trying to write an add-in for SOLIDWORKS and get familiar with the API. I started by adding a menu item

```cs
public bool ConnectToSW(object ThisSW, int Cookie)
{
    this.ThisSW = ThisSW as ISldWorks;
    this.Cookie = Cookie;

    this.ThisSW.SetAddinCallbackInfo2(0, this, this.Cookie);

    SwEventPtr = (SldWorks)this.ThisSW;

    this.ThisSW.AddMenuItem5((int)swDocumentTypes_e.swDocPART, this.Cookie, "Item@&File", 0, null, null, "My Menu Item", null);

    return true;
}
```

I've successfully registered the program containing the above snippet.
[image: List of Add-Ins registered]

However, when I open the **File** menu, there is no **Item** item. What am I doing wrong?
[image: No Item in File]

Comment: Try to create or open a part model, and check menu then.

Comment: I tried it there is still nothing

Answer (score 0):

the AddMenuItem5() function is not working for me too (maybe a bug).
You could use an older version e.g. AddMenuItem3()

Be aware that the menu item is only visible when a part document is opened. To make it visible with other document types change the first parameter accordingly. Use the swDocNone to always display the menu item.

```
this.ThisSW.AddMenuItem3((int)swDocumentTypes_e.swDocPART, this.Cookie, "Item@&File", -1, "MyMenuCallback", "MyMenuEnableMethod", "My menu item", "");
```